# Rails Add link_to Parameter if Provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched but haven't found an answer for this specifically yet. I'd like to use the same edit action for objects which may or may not have a parameter called city_id.  If the city_id is available, then I'd like to send it along to the edit page.  My question is how do I make the code below have only send the city_id if it is available?  Right now I get an error because not all of the objects have city_ids.

```
<%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => loc.id, :city_id => loc.city_id}) %>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried `try`? You could do `:city_id => loc.try(:city_id)`

Comment: This said, I am not very fond of `try`, but might help you in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  I just put that in and am getting an error "undefined local variable or method `city_id'" which I didn't get before.

Comment: Well, it should return `nil`. Are you really sure you replaced it? Can you show me your new code?

Comment: Okay, it worked in my example below and I think I had the name wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches:

Approach 1:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", { :action => 'edit', :id => loc.id, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id) }) %>
```

Pros: Less Code

Cons: urls will have `?city_id=` hanging even if there is no `city_id`

Approach 2:

```
<% if loc.city_id.present? %>
  <%= link_to("Edit", { :action => 'edit', :id => loc.id, :city_id => loc.city_id }) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to("Edit", { :action => 'edit', :id => loc.id }) %>
<% end %>
```

Pros: Explicit, no `?city_id=` hanging if there is no `city_id`

Cons: More verbose

===

Besides, it is always good to use the named routes, rather than `link_to`. Based on the parameters you are passing, assuming you have the following defined in the `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :locs
```

I would use one of the following:

Approach 1:

```
<%= edit_loc_url(loc, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id)) %>
```

Pros: Less Code, routes get updated with changes in the application

Cons: urls will have `?city_id=` hanging even if there is no `city_id`

Approach 2:

```
<% if loc.city_id.present? %>
  <%= edit_loc_url(loc, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id)) %>
<% else %>
  <%= edit_loc_url(loc, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id)) %>
<% end %>
```

Pros: Explicit, routes get updated with changes in the application, no `?city_id=` hanging if there is no `city_id`

Con: More verbose

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've been searching all over for something like this and your examples are VERY helpful and detailed!

Comment: I used a modification of your last code suggestion:

`<% if loc.city_id.present? %>
 <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit_pub', :id => loc.id, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id)}) %>
     <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete_pub', :id => loc.id, :city_id => loc.try(:city_id)}) %>
    <% else %>
       <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit_pub', :id => loc.id}) %>
       <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete_pub', :id => loc.id}) %>
    <% end %> `